# Override Sorting f(n) of UltraGrid

Tags: sorting, grouping, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I just want to know whether Infragistics provide such power to the developers to override its UltraGrid's sorting f(n)s. Whenever i have applied sorting on Grid's particular column, i got incorrect sorting result.

Asc Order came in my appl: (-)Hyphen, SPACES, 20, 100, 5000.

Desired Asc Order should be: 20, 100, 500, (-)Hyphen, SPACES.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UltraGridColumn has a property [SortComparer](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v15.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~SortComparer.html).
You can pass your custom [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.IComparer)&rd=true) class to this property in order to perform custom sorting of the gird's column.